# Syntax for excel source specific range with spaces in sheet name

Tags: ssis-2008

I would like to read a specific range on worksheet in an xlsx file with SSIS 2008.

To open the whole sheet, I need to add 'Report Data 1' in the "OpenRowset" field under advanced settings in the excel data source panel.
Now, I need everything from line 3 (including headers), so I assumed 'Report Data 1'$A3:K would be the good choice, but didn't work. I tried a few other combinations, but none of these work:

`'Report Data 1$A3:K'`
`[Report Data 1]$A3:K`
`'[Report Data 1]$A3:K'`

I also tried with fixed amount of rows, didn't help.

The error I'm getting is:
`Error at Data Flow Task [Excel Source [9]]: Opening a rowset for "'Report Data 1'$A3:K100" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.`

I tried with another test sheet and if there's no space in the sheet name, I can read the range with `Sheet1$A3:K4` in the OpenRowset property. What is the proper syntax for the openrowset property?

Comment: Could you better explain the task ? ..import a piece of data from an Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: I have extracts from Sharepoint logs, made every month. The first row contains the site URL, the second is empty, and from the 3rd row come the headers and the data. I did some research, how to skip the first x rows and the generic solution - define the range to read - doesn't work on this sheet. The only thing I can think on is that it has spaces in its name.

Comment: It could be a source problem of setting, in Excel Source Editor choose Data acces mode: SQL Command and write in SQL command text: SELECT * FROM [Report Data 1$A3:K]

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4150/how-to-read-data-from-an-excel-file-starting-from-the-nth-row-with-sql-server-integration-services/

Comment: Alex, the SELECT * FROM [Report Data 1$A3:K] solution worked, if you post it as an answer I will mark it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be a source problem of setting, in Excel Source Editor choose Data acces mode: SQL Command and write in SQL command text:

```
SELECT * FROM [Report Data 1$A3:K]
```